# align two buttons horizontally mvc5 razor c#

Tags: c#, css, twitter-bootstrap, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to get the save button and go back button to appear on the same row: I've truncated the code a bit for clarity:
I think i'm running into issues because one button is part of a form and the other is not. Initially i tried making them a part of the same `<div class="row"></div>` but to no avail.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ ...
<div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" id="savebtn" />
                </div>
            </div>
           </div>
}
```

```
@Html.ActionLink("Go Back", "Create", null, new { @class = "gobackbtnedit"})
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be worth tagging your question with *CSS*, as it is a basic layout issue, really.

If you picture your form taking up a rectangular space, then having the link displayed within it is usually going to involve either:

- Doing absolute positioning for your link to force its position.
- Placing the link inside the form.
- Placing the link *beside* the form, aligned so it is next to the button (which would have to be on the edge of the form).

I personally would just place the link inside the form, as if it needs to be placed next to the button, then there must be a logical connection between the link and the form.

```
<div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-5">
  <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" id="savebtn" />
</div>
<div class="col-md-5">
  @Html.ActionLink("Go Back", "Create", null, new { @class = "gobackbtnedit"})
</div>
```

An ActionLink really is just a `<a>` HTML element, which is fine in the form.  What's the reason for needing it outside?

Comment: no reason to why it was outside but,changed the code to the above and put it inside the form. The result remains the same: http://imgur.com/a/TpzYv